# pip2.7 install --user chromedriver_installer - unable to install

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

15:12 ~ $ pip2.7 install --user chromedriver_installer
Collecting chromedriver_installer
  Downloading chromedriver_installer-0.0.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: chromedriver-installer
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for chromedriver-installer ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpg9ElMzpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/chromedriver_installer
  copying chromedriver_installer/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/chromedriver_installer
  running build_scripts
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 220, in 
      cmdclass=dict(build_scripts=BuildScripts, install=Install)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 119, in run
      chromedriver_version = get_chromedriver_version()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 47, in get_chromedriver_version
      .format(CHROMEDRIVER_INFO_URL))
  Exception: Unable to get latest chromedriver version from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

---

Failed building wheel for chromedriver-installer
  Running setup.py clean for chromedriver-installer
Failed to build chromedriver-installer
Installing collected packages: chromedriver-installer
  Running setup.py install for chromedriver-installer ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CnRwTc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/chromedriver_installer
    copying chromedriver_installer/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/chromedriver_installer
    running build_scripts
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 220, in 
        cmdclass=dict(build_scripts=BuildScripts, install=Install)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      cmd_obj.run()
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 190, in run
        install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 119, in run
        chromedriver_version = get_chromedriver_version()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py", line 47, in get_chromedriver_version
        .format(CHROMEDRIVER_INFO_URL))
    Exception: Unable to get latest chromedriver version from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/setup.py';exec(compile(g
etattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CnRwTc-record/install-record.tx
t --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s8XaGy/chromedriver-installer/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't really work on PythonAnywhere, so there's not much point to having chromedriver installed.

More info here: http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/